# custom list control in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, list

I am trying to get something like in this screenshot [image]
<sub>(source: [smokingapples.com](http://smokingapples.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/socialite-hud.jpg))</sub>

in cocoa, I mean a custom list control. Do you know how this kind of things can be done?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

NSTableView now supports view-based rows with variable heights:

> **`- (NSTableViewRowSizeStyle)rowSizeStyle`**
>
> **Return Value**
> The row style style. See `NSTableViewRowSizeStyle` for the supported options.
>
> **Discussion**
> The row size style can be modified on a row by row basis by invoking the delegate method `tableView:heightOfRow:`, if implemented.
>
> The `rowSizeStyle` defaults to `NSTableViewRowSizeStyleCustom`. `NSTableViewRowSizeStyleCustom` indicates to use the rowHeight of the table, instead of the pre-determined system values.
>
> Generally, `rowSizeStyle` should always be `NSTableViewRowSizeStyleCustom` except for "source lists". To implement variable row heights, set the value to `NSTableViewRowSizeStyleCustom` and implement `tableView:heightOfRow:` in the delegate.
>
> **Availability**
> Available in OS X v10.7 and later.

---

**Original Answer:**

An approach, that's more modern than view hacking NSTableView would be either one of these:

http://github.com/sdegutis/SDListView

> **SDListView** - Clone of NSCollectionView, but with
> variable-height items and only using a
> single column.

http://github.com/uliwitness/PXListView

> **PXListView** - An optimized list view control for Mac
> OS X 10.5 and greater. It was created
> after I wrote [this post](http://perspx.com/blog/archives/1427/making-list-views-really-fast/) on the
> subject.
>
> PXListView is licensed under the New
> BSD license.
>
> PXListView uses similar optimizations
> as UITableView for the iPhone, by
> enqueuing and dequeuing NSViews which
> are used to display rows, in order to
> keep a low memory footprint when there
> are a large number of rows in the
> list, yet still allowing each row to
> be represented by an NSView, which is
> easier than dealing with cells.
>
> The architecture of the control is
> based on the list view controls which
> are present in both Tweetie (Mac) and
> Echofon (Mac).
>
> The project is still very much a work
> in progress, and as such no
> documentation exists at current.

[Edit: it case it wasn't obvious: the class descriptions seen above are quotations of course ;) Where "I" in the latter one actually refers to "Alex Rozanski", not me.]

Comment: Glad I could help.
Btw, would you mind leaving a short comment once you've made your choice and elaborate briefly on why you chose SDListView over PXListView? (or vice versa, or maybe even none of both)

Comment: I've started to implement SDListView. The reason is really simple: just because I prefer its scrollbar.

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple `NSTableView` with a redrawn table cell which consists of `NSImageView` and a fiew customized `NSTextField`s.

Comment: I was wondering something more complex. Thanks for your answer.